# Rótulo não aparece no gráfico

Tags: r, barplot

Olá,

Minha configuração é a seguinte:

> ```
> > sessionInfo()
> ```
>
> **R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)**
>
> **Platform:** x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
>
> **locale:**
>   _LC_COLLATE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252_, _LC_CTYPE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252_, _LC_MONETARY=Portuguese_Brazil.1252_, _LC_NUMERIC=C_ and _LC_TIME=Portuguese_Brazil.1252_
>
> **attached base packages:** 
>   *stats*, *graphics*, *grDevices*, *utils*, *datasets*, *methods* and *base*

Estou elaborando alguns gráficos e, em especial, estou apanhando de um BarPlot com o seguinte código:

```
    ## ClienteUF
var_check = mydata$ClienteUF
mytable<-table(var_check)

freq(var_check,main="Unidade da Federação",plot = FALSE)
#Fitting Labels
par(las=2) # make label text perpendicular to axis
par(mar=c(4,4,2,2)) # increase y-axis margin.
percentlabels<- round(100*table(var_check)/sum(table(var_check)), 1)
barlabels<- paste(percentlabels, "%", sep="")

graphlabels <- 
  barplot(table(var_check), main="Unidade da Federação",cex.names=0.7, 
          names.arg = names(mytable), yaxp=c(0,max(mytable)+5,5),
          las = 1)
## Add text at top of bars
text(x = xx, y = mytable, label = barlabels, pos = 3, cex = 0.8, col = "red")
```

O gráfico mostrado é esse:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe como fazer aparecer o rótulo na barra de SP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O teu exemplo não é reproduzível, pois não temos acesso aos teus dados. Imagino que aumentar o limite do eixo y resolva o teu problema:

```
barplot(table(var_check), main="Unidade da Federação",cex.names=0.7, 
      names.arg = names(mytable), yaxp=c(0,max(mytable)+5,5),
      las = 1, ylim=c(0, 110))
```

Não sei se 110 é o melhor valor para o teu gráfico. Por isso, altere o limite superior do argumento `ylim=c(0, 110)` para que o teu gráfico fique esteticamente mais bonito. A melhor maneira de fazer isto, creio eu, seja por tentativa e erro.

Comment: Obrigado @Marcus, era isso mesmo :)